# Got error return code 7005 While running my Game on Huawei device

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am trying to integrate some of HMS Game engine features to optimize my Game performance, but I got an error return code is 7005. Below is my code. Could someone tell me what went wrong?

```
public class GameSummaryActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gamesummary);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn_get_local_gamesummary)
public void getLocalGameSummary() {
    GameSummaryClient client = Games.getGameSummaryClient(this);
    Task<GameSummary> task = client.getLocalGameSummary();
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<GameSummary>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(GameSummary gameSummary) {
            showLog("achievementCount:" + gameSummary.getAchievementCount());
            showLog("appId:" + gameSummary.getAppId());
            showLog("descInfo:" + gameSummary.getDescInfo());
            showLog("gameName:" + gameSummary.getGameName());
            showLog("gameHdImgUri:" + gameSummary.getGameHdImgUri());
            showLog("gameIconUri:" + gameSummary.getGameIconUri());
            showLog("rankingCount:" + gameSummary.getRankingCount());
            showLog("firstKind:" + gameSummary.getFirstKind());
            showLog("secondKind:" + gameSummary.getSecondKind());
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof ApiException) {
                String result = "rtnCode:" + ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                showLog(result);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Result code 7005 indicates that a request parameter, such as appid or cpid, is incorrect. Perform the following check:

• If you are using Android Studio, ensure that the agconnect-services.json file is stored in your app's root directory of your project.

• If you are using Eclipse, ensure that you have integrated the HMS Core Game Service SDK correctly by instructions in our documents.